# DIY: Project remove VGA cable by sharing screen over wifi to TV

Tags: linux, video-streaming, screenshot, screen-capture

This is one of my coding projects. I'm fairly new to linux, so I need some pointers and thoughts from you guys, before I get started. I know there exists screen sharing software already, but I want to make my own! (=

Specifically, I want to clone my laptop screen to my TV over WLAN, via a linux box that is connected to a TV through a VGA cable:

1. Laptop streams it's screen
2. Linux box reads the stream
3. Linux box outputs the stream into the TV (through a VGA cable)

First of all, how do I record the screen and send the stream in real time in linux?

Secondly I must write a program that reads the stream being sent. The program must listen to some port, and collect the data being streamed from the laptop. Any thoughts?

Then I must output that data in real time to the TV. Do you how any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Edit: Regarding programming languages, I'm most comfortable with python.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing your screen can be done via the various flavors of [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) (ie. [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/), [TightVNC](http://tightvnc.com/), [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/), etc.). [Most](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-tight/) of [them](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ultravnc/) are Open Source, you might want to:

1. Stick with the VNC protocol for later compatibility
2. Take example of how the established solutions does for screen-hooking.

In Linux, the graphics are all processed by Xorg (new version of X Server), which was developed with networking embedded. This explains why you can ssh -X into a machine, execute a graphical interface on it and see it on your remote computer. I recommend you to read about hooks on Xorg to achieve your needs.

You need a client-server topology to achieve your needs. You are not talking about any programming language you forecast to use, though. Some languages may be harder than some to start with. Furthermore, this kind of code is already really well understood under every major programming language. You should try to at least use a framework that simplifies your networking portion of the project.

Sharing a screen on the TV can be done by your video card driver in Linux. Just check on your Desktop Environment (KDE and Gnome offers video configuration panels, for example) or in your video card configuration (nVidia and ATI Linux drivers offers multiple screen support)

It seems to me like you're trying to reinvent the wheel and are not too sure about how to begin. I recommend you to begin simple with one of the already proven VNC software and see how it goes from there. If a feature is missing, you've got the source code of the server and the client, so you can continue development of these projects. Once you've got your setup working, start thinking about replacing a single piece of the puzzle by your own code, and see how it goes.

Do not expect good (full HD, for instance) video quality on your TV without some very capable CPU/GPU and a 802.11n wireless network empty of users and be ready to accept some lag for the codecs to kick in.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to take as small steps as possible. If I were taking up such a project, my first step would be to try to implement a solution using standard unix tools (e.g. `netcat` or `socat` for the network part, `mplayer` or `vlc` for the playback and maybe `ffmpeg` for the capture)? Then, replace each component with custom-written ones if needed.